# Pandas pivot table

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

When I run my code using Pandas on Windows it works well, however when running on Ubuntu I get the following error:

```
canceled_Table = pd.pivot_table(canceled, index = 'end', columns = 'pcode', values = 'quantity', aggfunc = np.sum)
```

> TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

anyone know why?

Comment: Are you running an older version of pandas on ubuntu? Can you post `pandas.__version__`, if you're running a version older than `0.16.0` then the params names are different, try `canceled_Table = pd.pivot_table(canceled, rows = 'end', cols = 'pcode', values = 'quantity', aggfunc = np.sum)`, see [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6581)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly likely that your pandas versions are different, on windows you're running a version `0.16.0` or newer and your ubuntu version is older. There was an api change in [`0.16.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes), the older api used `rows` and `cols` but this was changed to `index` and `columns` respectively for consistency.

You can either upgrade or try the following:

```
canceled_Table = pd.pivot_table(canceled, rows = 'end', cols = 'pcode', values = 'quantity', aggfunc = np.sum)
```